# How do I get something from inside a project to a directory? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, file, copy

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace msoApplier
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string targetPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram";          

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            System.IO.File.Copy("ExampleProgram.exe", targetPath);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

ExampleProgram.exe is in the same folder as Program.cs. Is there anything I can do?
I don't want ExampleProgram.exe to be seperate from the program, I want it to be inside the program, and then copied to that place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to store ExampleProgram.exe inside the program that your source code produces. If that is the case, you can store that ExampleProgram.exe as a resource within your program then read the resource and store it at the location of your choice.

Comment: I'll go and try that. Thanks!

Comment: If this answers your question. Please mark it as the answer. And possibly even provide a few lines showing the code that worked to your question so others can see the solution too.

Answer (score 0):

How about to get the Path of your executing exe? Then you could spezify the copy process with the whole Path?

eg.:

```
string SourceDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string SourceFile = SourceDir + "\ExampleProgram.exe";
System.IO.File.Copy(SourceFile , targetPath);
```

Haven't tested it, because I'm not at Work.

Kind Regards